# C++ "'stdarg.h' file not found" in "wchar.h" on save in Sublime Text

Tags: c++, c++11, sublimetext3, llvm, header-files

I am seeing the message

```
/usr/include/wchar.h:89:10: fatal error: 'stdarg.h' file not found
```

on the console when I save .cpp files in Sublime Text 3, Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38), macOS Sierra. The files do seem to save and build correctly, however. I would appreciate it if anyone could help me understand what is going on.

Edit: I am just starting out with C++, but the line in question appears to come from the default "wchar.h" file on macOS, the relevant lines of which are

```
#ifndef _WCHAR_H_
#define _WCHAR_H_

#include <_types.h>
#include <sys/cdefs.h>
#include <Availability.h>

#include <sys/_types/_null.h>
#include <sys/_types/_size_t.h>
#include <sys/_types/_mbstate_t.h>
#include <sys/_types/_ct_rune_t.h>
#include <sys/_types/_rune_t.h>
#include <sys/_types/_wchar_t.h>

#ifndef WCHAR_MIN
#define WCHAR_MIN   __DARWIN_WCHAR_MIN
#endif

#ifndef WCHAR_MAX
#define WCHAR_MAX   __DARWIN_WCHAR_MAX
#endif

#include <stdarg.h>
```

The error message shows up when I save a file like this:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()            
{
    cout << "Hello, World!\n";      
    return 0;
}
```

where "std_lib_facilities.h" is from http://stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h, but the error message does not appear to be specific only to this file.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and edit your question

Comment: I added some more detail, if that addresses the issue.

Comment: Is it compiling on save or literally complaining just for a save? If the latter I would check to see if you have some package installed that tries to do autocompletion for C code; it may be trying to scan your file on every save and not know where to find things.

Comment: @OdatNurd Thanks, the latter – turns out I was using an outdated autocomplete package, so installing a new one fixed the problem.

Comment: @wander, can you tell which package that was?

Comment: @igrek If I remember correctly, the problematic package was [Clang-Complete](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Clang-Complete). Switching to [EasyClangComplete](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/EasyClangComplete) solved the issue for me.

Comment: thanks, that helps, now i have another problem.. :D when my project is compiled it uses gtest as a library so an include like `#include "gtest/gtest.h"` works, sublime does not know how to locate that library though :\